# IIS, Web services, Time out error

Tags: asp.net, web-services, iis

We’ve got problem with ASP.NET web application that uses web services of other system.  I’ll describe our system architecture: we have web application and Windows services that uses the same web services.
- Windows service works all the time and sends information to these web services once an hour.
- Web application is designed for users to send the same information in manual behavior.

The problem is when user sometimes tries to send information in manual behavior in the web application, .NET throws exception „The operation has timed out” (web?). At that time Windows service successfully sends all necessary information to these web services. IT stuff that supports these web services asserts that there was no any request from our web application at that time. Then we have restarted IIS (iisreset) and everything has started to work fine. 
This situation repeats all the time. There is no anti-virus or firewall on the server. 
My suggestion is that there is something wrong with IIS, patches, configuration or whatever?
The only specific thing is that there are requests that can least 2 minutes (web service response wait time).

We tried to reproduce this situation on our local test servers, but everything works fine. 
OS: Windows Server 2003 R2
.NET: 3.5

Comment: Are these ASMX web services or WCF web services?

Answer (score 0):

In the web application there should be a basicHttpBinding entry in the Web.config relating to the webservice you want to use.

There are several attributes that may help
closeTimeout
openTimeout
receiveTimeout
sendTimeout

please see here for their meanings : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731361.aspx

Hope this helps